# Deployed wrong app to Google Cloud, how to prevent?

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

When I run `gcloud app deploy` I get the message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) The required property [project] is not currently set.
You may set it for your current workspace by running:

  $ gcloud config set project VALUE

or it can be set temporarily by the environment variable [CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT]
```

Setting the project in my current workspace caused me to deploy the wrong app, so I don't want to do that again. I want to try deploying using the environment variable option listed above. How do I do this? What is the deploy syntax to use CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT? I thought this would come from my app.yaml but haven't gotten it working.

Answer (score 4):

You should configure it with your project using projectID.

```
gcloud config set project <PROJECT_ID>
```

You can find your projectID your GCP account.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to pass the project as part of the app deploy command:

`gcloud app deploy ~/my_app/app.yaml --project=PROJECT`

Look at the examples in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy).

Comment: What does your app.yaml look like in this case? And where is `CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT` set? I don't see this anywhere in the documentation, just in the console message

Comment: Can't you set the project id in the app.yaml and then just run `gcloud app deploy`? Why do we have to include the --project flag in the command? Can't gcloud read it from the app.yaml?

Comment: No, you cannot set project ID in app.yaml. Per @grappler answer you can either use `gcloud app deploy ... --project=${PROJECT}`, or you can set the environment variable `CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT=${PROJECT} gcloud app deploy ...`

Comment: So.. I work in many apps and now deploy to multiple gcloud app engines, any suggestions for a good workflow here? I feel like I'm missing something. In heroku it's impossible to deploy the wrong app because you push to a git remote.. not sure why google cloud can't have something in place like "hey, this is the wrong app for that remote"

Comment: I am looking for the same answer @nateM. Did you find a solution? Seems weird to have one main project when you use cloud for many sites and can push to the wrong one!

Comment: No I haven't found a solution yet. In fact I almost deployed the wrong project to a production site again! We humans like to fat finger things.. help us out google!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message recently in a job which worked fine before.
Old:

```
# Deploy template
.deploy_template: &deploy_definition
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo $GOOGLE_KEY > key.json
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file key.json
    - gcloud config set compute/zone $GC_REGION
    - gcloud config set project $GC_PROJECT
    - gcloud container clusters get-credentials $GC_XXX_CLUSTER
    - kubectl set image deployment/XXXXXX --record
```

New:

```
# Deploy template
.deploy_template: &deploy_definition
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo $GOOGLE_KEY > key.json
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file key.json
    - gcloud config set project $GC_PROJECT
    - gcloud config set compute/zone $GC_REGION
    - gcloud container clusters get-credentials $GC_XXX_CLUSTER
    - kubectl set image deployment/XXXXXX --record
```

I just change the order of `compute/zone`, and it is worked like before.